# how to set tmux window title and see this in choose-tree

Tags: zsh, tmux

I have two MacOS machines both running zsh and tmux for a local developer environment. The machine I'm stumped on (referred to as machine 2) is reflected in the screen shot. What is not happening is for window 1. I expect it to show `zsh* (1 panes) "michael@Michaels-MBP:~/Documents"`. On machine 1, it does show this.

I am running zsh and oh-my-zsh. tmux and osx plugin enabled.
I am running tmux and oh-my-tmux.

I cannot figure out where or what to set to get tmux to behave like it does on machine 1. When I am just in the terminal emulator with zsh, the terminal tab title is `michael@Michaels-MBP:~/Documents`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply rebind the default `choose-tree` binding to list the windows according to the format you're looking for:

```
bind-key w choose-tree -ZF "#{window_name}* (#{window_panes} panes) #{host}:#{pane_path}"
```

For more information on tmux's FORMAT options, you can reference the [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/tmux#Formats).