# choose-tree default format

Tags: tmux

When switching from a session to another, with `<prefix> s`, I want to print the git branch beside the session name.

I know how to update the format of that "window" (explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689728/163665)), but I don't want to remove something inadvertently.

**My question:**
What is the default format for tmux choose-tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found it [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/6a8d848a3e123ec5a0bb9747522a343c843f1c61/window-tree.c#L39), if anyone else is looking for it

```
#define WINDOW_TREE_DEFAULT_FORMAT \
"#{?pane_format," \
    "#{?pane_marked,#[reverse],}" \
    "#{pane_current_command}#{?pane_active,*,}#{?pane_marked,M,}" \
    "#{?#{&&:#{pane_title},#{!=:#{pane_title},#{host_short}}},: \"#{pane_title}\",}" \
"," \
    "#{?window_format," \
        "#{?window_marked_flag,#[reverse],}" \
        "#{window_name}#{window_flags}" \
        "#{?#{&&:#{==:#{window_panes},1},#{&&:#{pane_title},#{!=:#{pane_title},#{host_short}}}},: \"#{pane_title}\",}" \
    "," \
        "#{session_windows} windows" \
        "#{?session_grouped, " \
            "(group #{session_group}: " \
            "#{session_group_list})," \
        "}" \
        "#{?session_attached, (attached),}" \
    "}" \
"}"
```